# No addresses to dial nor connected peers while setting up tendermint(only single node)

Tags: nodes, bigchaindb, tendermint

```
I[09-09|17:39:49.600] Starting socketClient                        module=abci-client connection=mempool impl=socketClient
I[09-09|17:39:49.708] Starting socketClient                        module=abci-client connection=consensus impl=socketClient
I[09-09|17:39:49.760] ABCI Handshake                               module=consensus appHeight=0 appHash=
I[09-09|17:39:49.760] ABCI Replay Blocks                           module=consensus appHeight=0 storeHeight=0 stateHeight=0
I[09-09|17:39:49.869] Completed ABCI Handshake - Tendermint and App are synced module=consensus appHeight=0 appHash=
I[09-09|17:39:49.869] This node is a validator                     module=consensus addr=B01608A3D85CFC90CF0F224D206C7AE785403A7C pubKey=PubKeyEd25519{05C12BE16BB6ACA772A97105B66B4BBA9A2E39DED6B4416542D9D19059F338AC}
I[09-09|17:39:49.907] Starting Node                                module=main impl=Node
I[09-09|17:39:49.907] Starting EventBus                            module=events impl=EventBus
I[09-09|17:39:49.907] Local listener                               module=p2p ip=:: port=26656
I[09-09|17:39:49.907] Starting DefaultListener                     module=p2p impl=Listener(@192.168.1.22:26656)
I[09-09|17:39:49.908] P2P Node ID                                  module=main ID=22699e97da6e120e0b017f86077a7fe2e9eb869a file=/root/.tendermint/config/node_key.json
I[09-09|17:39:49.908] Add our address to book                      module=p2p book=/root/.tendermint/config/addrbook.json addr=22699e97da6e120e0b017f86077a7fe2e9eb869a@192.168.1.22:26656
I[09-09|17:39:49.908] Starting RPC HTTP server on tcp://0.0.0.0:26657 module=rpc-server 
I[09-09|17:39:49.908] Starting P2P Switch                          module=p2p impl="P2P Switch"
I[09-09|17:39:49.908] Starting MempoolReactor                      module=mempool impl=MempoolReactor
I[09-09|17:39:49.909] Starting BlockchainReactor                   module=blockchain impl=BlockchainReactor
I[09-09|17:39:49.909] Starting ConsensusReactor                    module=consensus impl=ConsensusReactor
I[09-09|17:39:49.909] ConsensusReactor                             module=consensus fastSync=false
I[09-09|17:39:49.909] Starting ConsensusState                      module=consensus impl=ConsensusState
I[09-09|17:39:49.909] Starting baseWAL                             module=consensus wal=/root/.tendermint/data/cs.wal/wal impl=baseWAL
I[09-09|17:39:49.921] Starting TimeoutTicker                       module=consensus impl=TimeoutTicker
I[09-09|17:39:49.921] Catchup by replaying consensus messages      module=consensus height=1
I[09-09|17:39:49.921] Replay: Done                                 module=consensus 
I[09-09|17:39:49.921] Starting EvidenceReactor                     module=evidence impl=EvidenceReactor
I[09-09|17:39:49.921] Starting PEXReactor                          module=p2p impl=PEXReactor
I[09-09|17:39:49.921] Starting AddrBook                            module=p2p book=/root/.tendermint/config/addrbook.json impl=AddrBook
I[09-09|17:39:49.921] Saving AddrBook to file                      module=p2p book=/root/.tendermint/config/addrbook.json size=0
I[09-09|17:39:49.922] Ensure peers                                 module=p2p numOutPeers=0 numInPeers=0 numDialing=0 numToDial=10
I[09-09|17:39:49.934] Starting IndexerService                      module=txindex impl=IndexerService
I[09-09|17:39:49.934] Started node                                 module=main nodeInfo="NodeInfo{id: 22699e97da6e120e0b017f86077a7fe2e9eb869a, moniker: as-VirtualBox, network: test-chain-TqCtG5 [listen 192.168.1.22:26656], version: 0.22.8-40d6dc2e ([amino_version=0.10.1 p2p_version=0.5.0 consensus_version=v1/0.2.2 rpc_version=0.7.0/3 tx_index=on rpc_addr=tcp://0.0.0.0:26657])}"
I[09-09|17:39:49.936] No addresses to dial nor connected peers. Falling back to seeds module=p2p 
I[09-09|17:39:50.897] Timed out                                    module=consensus dur=974.45501ms height=1 round=0 step=RoundStepNewHeight
I[09-09|17:39:50.898] enterNewRound(1/0). Current: 1/0/RoundStepNewHeight module=consensus height=1 round=0
I[09-09|17:39:50.898] enterPropose(1/0). Current: 1/0/RoundStepNewRound module=consensus height=1 round=0
I[09-09|17:39:50.899] enterPropose: Our turn to propose            module=consensus height=1 round=0 proposer=B01608A3D85CFC90CF0F224D206C7AE785403A7C privValidator="PrivValidator{B01608A3D85CFC90CF0F224D206C7AE785403A7C LH:0, LR:0, LS:0}"
I[09-09|17:39:50.908] Signed proposal                              module=consensus height=1 round=0 proposal="Proposal{1/0 1:C6B8EA2F77F6 (-1,:0:000000000000) /93CE5D9BEB09.../ @ 2018-09-09T17:39:50.900Z}"
I[09-09|17:39:50.921] Received proposal                            module=consensus proposal="Proposal{1/0 1:C6B8EA2F77F6 (-1,:0:000000000000) /93CE5D9BEB09.../ @ 2018-09-09T17:39:50.900Z}"
I[09-09|17:39:50.927] Received complete proposal block             module=consensus height=1 hash=5B6D5AD1F81F4FC39AD926527C183D60C8D3D637
I[09-09|17:39:50.927] enterPrevote(1/0). Current: 1/0/RoundStepPropose module=consensus 
I[09-09|17:39:50.928] enterPrevote: ProposalBlock is valid         module=consensus height=1 round=0
I[09-09|17:39:50.937] Signed and pushed vote                       module=consensus height=1 round=0 vote="Vote{0:B01608A3D85C 1/00/1(Prevote) 5B6D5AD1F81F /674104AFC96A.../ @ 2018-09-09T17:39:50.928Z}" err=null
I[09-09|17:39:50.944] Added to prevote                             module=consensus vote="Vote{0:B01608A3D85C 1/00/1(Prevote) 5B6D5AD1F81F /674104AFC96A.../ @ 2018-09-09T17:39:50.928Z}" prevotes="VoteSet{H:1 R:0 T:1 +2/3:5B6D5AD1F81F4FC39AD926527C183D60C8D3D637:1:C6B8EA2F77F6(1) BA{1:x} map[]}"
I[09-09|17:39:50.944] enterPrecommit(1/0). Current: 1/0/RoundStepPrevote module=consensus height=1 round=0
I[09-09|17:39:50.945] enterPrecommit: +2/3 prevoted proposal block. Locking module=consensus height=1 round=0 hash=5B6D5AD1F81F4FC39AD926527C183D60C8D3D637
I[09-09|17:39:50.951] Signed and pushed vote                       module=consensus height=1 round=0 vote="Vote{0:B01608A3D85C 1/00/2(Precommit) 5B6D5AD1F81F /6BA76EE2998F.../ @ 2018-09-09T17:39:50.945Z}" err=null
I[09-09|17:39:50.958] Added to precommit                           module=consensus vote="Vote{0:B01608A3D85C 1/00/2(Precommit) 5B6D5AD1F81F /6BA76EE2998F.../ @ 2018-09-09T17:39:50.945Z}" precommits="VoteSet{H:1 R:0 T:2 +2/3:5B6D5AD1F81F4FC39AD926527C183D60C8D3D637:1:C6B8EA2F77F6(1) BA{1:x} map[]}"
I[09-09|17:39:50.958] enterCommit(1/0). Current: 1/0/RoundStepPrecommit module=consensus height=1 commitRound=0
I[09-09|17:39:50.959] Commit is for locked block. Set ProposalBlock=LockedBlock module=consensus height=1 commitRound=0 blockHash=5B6D5AD1F81F4FC39AD926527C183D60C8D3D637
I[09-09|17:39:50.960] Finalizing commit of block with 0 txs        module=consensus height=1 hash=5B6D5AD1F81F4FC39AD926527C183D60C8D3D637 root=
I[09-09|17:39:50.963] Block{
  Header{
    ChainID:        test-chain-TqCtG5
    Height:         1
    Time:           2018-09-09 17:39:50.899575446 +0000 UTC
    NumTxs:         0
    TotalTxs:       0
    LastBlockID:    :0:000000000000
    LastCommit:     
    Data:           
    Validators:     5B37B3A3144CEE1554A248BA55BD39F31B2C37A6
    App:            
    Consensus:       D6B74BB35BDFFD8392340F2A379173548AE188FE
    Results:        
    Evidence:       
  }#5B6D5AD1F81F4FC39AD926527C183D60C8D3D637
  Data{

  }#
  EvidenceData{

  }#
  Commit{
    BlockID:    :0:000000000000
    Precommits: 
  }#
}#5B6D5AD1F81F4FC39AD926527C183D60C8D3D637 module=consensus 
I[09-09|17:39:51.086] Executed block                               module=state height=1 validTxs=0 invalidTxs=0
I[09-09|17:39:51.135] Committed state                              module=state height=1 txs=0 appHash=
I[09-09|17:39:51.135] Recheck txs                                  module=mempool numtxs=0 height=1
I[09-09|17:39:51.148] Indexed block                                module=txindex height=1
I[09-09|17:39:51.179] New websocket connection                     module=rpc-server protocol=websocket remote=127.0.0.1:42212
I[09-09|17:39:51.179] Starting wsConnection                        module=rpc-server protocol=websocket remote=127.0.0.1:42212 impl=wsConnection
I[09-09|17:39:51.196] Subscribe to query                           module=rpc remote=127.0.0.1:42212 query="tm.event='NewBlock'"
I[09-09|17:39:51.196] WSJSONRPC                                    module=rpc-server protocol=websocket remote=127.0.0.1:42212 method=subscribe
I[09-09|17:39:51.960] Timed out                                    module=consensus dur=810.602421ms height=2 round=0 step=RoundStepNewHeight
I[09-09|17:39:51.960] enterNewRound(2/0). Current: 2/0/RoundStepNewHeight module=consensus height=2 round=0
I[09-09|17:40:19.936] Ensure peers                                 module=p2p numOutPeers=0 numInPeers=0 numDialing=0 numToDial=10
I[09-09|17:40:19.936] No addresses to dial nor connected peers. Falling back to seeds module=p2p
```

No addresses to dial loops infinitely

Comment: Did you provide persistent peers or seeds? What guide are you following? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: I am following the guide: [link](http://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/server/en/latest/simple-network-setup.html#before-we-start) and when i run the command tendermint node, i get the above error

Comment: What indicates to you that this is an error?

Comment: I have run tendermint without bigchaindb to simulate 1 node connection using command: tendermint node --proxy_app=kvstore,ref:[link](https://tendermint.com/docs/introduction/quick-start.html#initialization),If I run this way I dont get the above message

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it has something to do with configuration.